# C++ Check if array created with 'new'

Tags: c++, memory

In C++ the `delete[]` is supposed to be used with arrays created by `new`. You can pass arrays into functions like this: `void method_with_array(int* array)`. How can you tell if an array created this way was created with `new`, so you can delete it properly.

Comment: *How can you tell if an array created this way was created with new, so you can delete it properly.* -- This is a serious design flaw if you're resorting to trying to figure out where your buffer was created.  Let the creator of the buffer know where and how the buffer got created, whether dynamically, whether it is a regular array, etc.

Comment: "`delete[]` is supposed to be used with arrays created by `new`". Wrong. `delete[]` is supposed to be used with arrays created by `new[]`. Plain `new` pairs with plain `delete`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't, so better not pass around pointers to things created with `new` or `new[]`. Use for example `std::vector` or if you really really really need a dynamically allocated array, `std::unique_ptr<T[]>`.

Comment: Out of interest, is there any good use case for `std::unique_ptr<T[]>` over `std::vector`?

Comment: @NeilButterworth I have never had to use that specialization. I imagine there could exist very niche situations where the tiny size and/or zero initialization overhead of a vector could matter.

Comment: @NeilButterworth - using an existing API to some library (or the operating system) you might get from it an unwrapped allocated buffer that you're supposed to manage the lifetime of.

Comment: @david  OK,. I'd just observe that in that situation you would want a custom deleter.

Comment: oh yeah, of course.  You've got to `::LocalFree` it (Windows) or whatever.  Some libraries have a callback you should use.  The API you're calling will document that, of course ...

Answer (score -1):

Usually a good rule is that whoever takes care of the allocation of an object should take care of releasing the object.

That said, if you are allocating and deleting the memory for an object in the same object/container/manager, you know what you are dealing with. In case the same pointer is used for one or multiple elements, you have different options:

- keep a variable that tells you which kind of `int*` member you have allocated
- allocate all the times an array, eventually of size 1
- use an std::vector even for storing a single element, as above.